# Laravel 4 User Authorization and Views

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4, laravel-blade

So I am working on a website, writing it using Laravel and Semantic UI. As part of this site, the users can log in from any page and once logged in should be correctly redirected back to whatever page they were on. However, once logged in, a part of the UI should change to show that they are logged in, as opposed to showing a login button.

Is there an easy way to do this? Various answers I have seen here rely on having multiple blade templates, one for users who are not logged in and another for user who are. Ideally, I would prefer to have a single blade template (called master) that i could simply override a section of when a user is correctly authenticated. Also ideally, this logic would not be tied to any specific controller or route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you may simply use something like this in your `master` layout:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    {{ 'User Is Logged In, Show A LogOut Button' }}
@else
    {{ 'User Is Not Logged In, Show A LogIn Button' }}
@endif
```

Comment: You can use this sort of logic in a blade template? Awesome! Do you happen to have a link to some documentation on this?